# how to manually set cookie status in ngx-cookieconsent for Angular

Tags: angular

I use ngx-cookieconsent module for an angular app, I need to manually set the cookie's status after a specific event but I didn't find a public method to do that in the injectable NgcCookieConsentService. Does anybody know if it is possible or if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

document.cookie = "user=John"; 
alert(document.cookie);

Comment: Ok I can set manually the cookie but I need to fire and Observable<NgcStatusChangeEvent> to manage the operation inside the subscribe function of that stream of observable. Setting manually the cookie that stream doesn't emit the observable but the problem seems the change detection, I tried to force change detection with angular ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() but nothing , the observable is emitted only when I perform an action on the dom (as a click).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to store. Think about using [Local Storage](https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/)

Here is the main difference :

> While these storage options have their positives and negatives, they both have applications in modern web development. Cookies are smaller and send server information back with every HTTP request, while LocalStorage is larger and can hold information on the client side. [Medium link](https://medium.com/swlh/cookies-vs-localstorage-whats-the-difference-d99f0eb09b44)

Local storage looks like this :

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value); //write 
let myItem = localStorage.getItem(key); //read
```